# Xcode 7 white screen when app is built and simulated

Tags: ios, xcode

When I hit the run button for my app,

> the simulator just shows a white screen

however there should be a button that says "Hello World". Also, for the label,

> an error message saying "Position is ambiguous for "Hello World"

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: pls provide more info!!! How and where did u set the button ? Storyboard ? Any constraints ? How you are loading the view ?

Comment: Your question is too unclear and very poor in terms of provided information. Share the code and show your view controllers with info about constraints

Comment: It is located in 'HelloWorldViewController.xib' and there are no constraints and it is running in an iPhone 6 simulator

Comment: What do you need to see the code of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraints to your hello world label.
You can add constraints to a view by selecting it and pressing on one of the constraint buttons on the bottom right side of the view editor.
Currently, it sounds like your label is displaying off screen.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to check the info.plist file, and make sure that you are pointing to the right value for the view you are trying to see in the simulator (ie. LaunchScreen.storyboard, or main.storyboard). I had the same issues, and made this change to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Best answer. I didn't notice that there is LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the view in the storyboard is connected to the file owner.
You may give a background color to the view just to check if the same is reflected on launch.  If yes,  you may add vertical and horizontal center align constraints to your label.
If no, then your view controller is not yet on the screen.
Please post your code.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open up HelloWorldViewController.xib by clicking on it. Select the Hello World button.  At the bottom right of the panel, you'll see a short row of icons.  Click the one highlighted below in red. Check off the `Horizontally in Container` and `Vertically in Container` items. The `Add Constraints` button at the bottom should then become active -- click it to add those two constraints.  Do the same for the label. Now run your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the position of the views are ambiguous and they are "displaying" off screen. Check out this link https://teamtreehouse.com/library/implementing-designs-for-iphone/implementing-custom-login-and-sign-up-screens/adding-background-images-and-positioning-views

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised none of the answers addressed an obvious issue as to why this might be happening. I just purchased a MacBook Air, the small 33 inch display.

When you run the emulator, it displays at 50 percent. On the Air, 50 percent is zoomed to close. Go to window > scale > 33% and you will see your content.